# How to use MatBlazor's MatTextField?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to make use of MatBlazor (version 1.1.1).
I am using this in an asp.net hosted model ( client & server projects). 
I am getting the following error for the below snippet:

[image: o]

```
<MatTextField bind-Value="@this.Row.StringValue" HelperText="@this.Row.Property" Label="@this.Row.Property"></MatTextField>
```

Note that the red error squiggly is underlining **@this.Row.StringValue**

**Resolved**
I just had to simply add the following to the top:

> @using MatBlazor

Comment: You should include the definition of Row, at least an outline. What kind of member is is StringValue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just dont add namespace

```
@using MatBlazor
```